# .prpt reports running from java

Tags: java, reporting, pentaho

Earlier I worked with Pentaho reports, where I can create report with pentaho report designer and deploy .prpt file onto into BI server.  It will work fine.

Now I am looking for a solution where I can put .prpt file in a Java program and run just like jasper reports (.jrxml files).  Because I need to integrate Pentaho reports with my web application.

I may be asking a very basic question.  But I did not find the proper document on this.  Please point me to some correct location and a sample code will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Since the first link in the accepted answer doesn't seem to work anymore, people who are looking for examples might find this more useful: https://github.com/pentaho/pentaho-reporting/blob/master/engine/samples/source/org/pentaho/reporting/engine/classic/samples

The code in some of the samples is a bit convoluted, so i'm posting my own report generator class, which only contains the bare essentials for generating a PDF report:

`public class ReportGenerator {`

```
  public byte[] generateReport(byte[] templateBytes, Map<String, Object> params) throws Exception {
    ClassicEngineBoot.getInstance().start();

    MasterReport reportData = loadTemplateDefinition(templateBytes);
    addParametersToReport(params, reportData);
    byte[] reportBytes = generateReport(reportData);

    return reportBytes;
  }

  private MasterReport loadTemplateDefinition(byte[] templateBytes) throws Exception {
    ResourceManager resourceManager = new ResourceManager();
    Resource templateResource = resourceManager.createDirectly(templateBytes, MasterReport.class);
    return (MasterReport) templateResource.getResource();
  }

  private void addParametersToReport(Map<String, Object> params, MasterReport reportData) {
    if (params != null) {
      for (String key : params.keySet()) {
        reportData.getParameterValues().put(key, params.get(key));
      }
    }
  }

  private byte[] generateReport(MasterReport reportData) throws ReportProcessingException {
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfOutputProcessor outputProcessor = new PdfOutputProcessor(reportData.getConfiguration(), outputStream, reportData.getResourceManager());

    AbstractReportProcessor reportProcessor = null;
    try {
      reportProcessor = new PageableReportProcessor(reportData, outputProcessor);
      reportProcessor.processReport();
    } finally {
      if (reportProcessor != null) {
        reportProcessor.close();
      }
    }

    return outputStream.toByteArray();
  }
}
```

The generateReport method accepts the contents of a .prpt file in the templateBytes parameter, and a list of parameters needed to generate the report in the params parameter.

The byte array it returns contains the contents of a generated PDF report.

Also if you are using Maven for your application it is important to include all the necessary dependencies. I used the list i found here: http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/Reporting/How+to+integrate+report+designer+to+your+web+application, and in it i replaced all the pentaho-related library versions with version 6.1.0.1-196

Answer (score 1):

I've embedded successfully the Pentaho Reporting Engine in my Java application. There is a tutorial with the necessary libraries and examples. The only thing you need to consider while starting is to use the same version of Pentaho SDK, Pentaho Reporting Engine and Pentaho Report Designer, to don't get datasource issues. If you don't want troubles about dependencies, you can download Pentaho Report Designer and drag and drop all the libraries into your web application (most of the issues come when you try to use pentaho charts, and they are solved in this way).

*Official Pentaho Docs:*

http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Freporting_embedders_guide%2Ftopic_embedding_engine.html

*Pentaho Reporting Classic Engine Core (better try with this first):*

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jfreereport/files/01.%20Classic%20Engine/

Just import all the libraries in your IDE (I used Eclipse Helios), and use the example provided, it will work as a charm!. Then you can start to modify it depending on your needs. I suggest you to review how to handle the path for the reports.

Comment: Hi Cho Cho,

Iam able to integrate the pentaho report with my application successfully. Report with Tabular data is generated fine but unable to get the reports with pie chart or bar chart. Do I need to add some more additional changes >

Comment: Praneeth, add these jars to your project: "legacy-charts", "jfreechart" and "jcommon". Be sure to match the same version of PRD and Reporting Engine. You can find these jars in the lib folder of you Report Designer path. Don't forget, match the same version (for example, PRD 5.1.0 and Reporting Engine 5.1.0) [link](http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?152813-Pentaho-does-display-chart-in-an-web-application)

Answer (score 0):

```
    final FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ClassicEngineBoot.getInstance().start();
    try {
        // load report definition
        ResourceManager manager = new ResourceManager();
        manager.registerDefaults();


        ExternalContext extContext = context.getExternalContext();


        String reportPath = "file:" + extContext.getRealPath("name/name.prpt");

        Resource res = manager.createDirectly(new URL(reportPath), MasterReport.class);
        MasterReport report = (MasterReport) res.getResource();


        ................
        ................

        httpServletResponse.setContentType("application/rtf");
        httpServletResponse.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"name.rtf\"");

        RTFReportUtil.createRTF(report, httpServletResponse.getOutputStream());

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();

    } catch (ReportProcessingException ex) {
```

Comment: Please include explanation of what your code does and how it answers the question. If you get a code snippet as an answer, you may not know what to do with it. Answer should give the OP guidance on how to debug and fix their problem. Pointing out, what the idea behind your code is, greatly helps in understanding the issue and applying or modifying your solution. Also your answer seems to answer the question only partially.

Comment: There is a project - https://github.com/tmorgner/pentaho-reporting-oem-sdk where a lot of reporting examples is shared with pentaho-reporting author comments